# When using a subprocess.Popen(command), would a password be exposed in a terminal log in any way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, passwords, subprocess

I need to execute a command multiple times which, when executed, asks for a password. However, the password could also be specified as a variable through "--cpass ".
I would like to use the module getpass to first get the password securely and then execute the command (multiple times) similar to:

```py
import getpass
import subprocess

password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password: ", stream=None) 

# later in a for-loop context:
    ....
    subprocess.Popen([command, "--cpass", password],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    ....
```

Will this approach "leak" or store the password in plain text in some terminal log somewhere? and if so, what could be a better approach?
(not providing the password through "--cpass " would result in a password-prompt for every command execution which would be very cumbersome for the user...)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html "Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call a system shell. This means that all characters, including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child processes." :)

Comment: @h4z3 Very well then :) If you add this as an answer instead of a comment I can mark it as solved. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations):

> ## Security Considerations
>
> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call a system shell. This means that all characters, including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child processes.

This part clearly claims that everything can be "passed safely", so that would include plaintext passwords.

If someone is still not convinced, password can be probably passed through normal communication with the process.